# Incremental backup and sync software

Tags: windows, backup, software-rec, incremental-backup

I need a free software for Windows (with gui or command line) that does incremental backup copying all files and storing changed or deleted files in a directory named like last change date (or a progressive number).

To be more precise:
D:\ is my Data drive
E:\ is my Backupdrive.

If i want to backup all my data from D::
E:\d_lastbackup\ will contain a plain copy of all the files and folder content (no compression or archiving, same files attributes) of D
E:\d_20090822\ will contain all files (with their full path) that are changed or deleted in the last version (since the previous one)
E:\d_20090820\ will contain all files (with their full path) that are changed or deleted in the last version (since the previous one)
and so on...

I had a software working prefectly with an old USB harddsik by Maxtor, but it works only on that device.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Cobian backup does separate folders, uncompressed, and supports incremental/differential.

http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm

Comment: Looks good. It's incremental, easy to set up, and can run as a background service so it doesn't clutter up my system tray. Just what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Cobian backup seems to have become very popular, and can be found here now: http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm . The other link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

I use [**7-zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/) for incremental compressed backups.
Here is a reference article: [**Powershell & 7Zip incremental backup solution**](http://wmug.co.uk/blogs/sean/archive/2009/03/20/powershell-amp-7zip-incremental-backup-solution.aspx).
That link has [a ready-script](http://wmug.co.uk/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/sean.PowerShell+Scripts/7ZipBackupScript.zip) for use.
<sub>But, you don't really need PowerShell -- the ability comes from **7z** itself.</sub>

Comment: This is a spectacular answer.  This coupled with WinSCP makes remote `rsync`'ing from a Windows box to anything dead simple.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I like using 7z for differential because if you use -u it will make anti-items for those files that were deleted.  That way all you need is the full backup and the diff to get back where you were.

Comment: Your link is broken. :(

Answer (score 5):

[DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) (basically a Windows version of [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)) and [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html) (3 versions to choose from, one free) sound right up your alley.

Answer (score 5):

I use [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) with some scripting I found on the 'net that adds VSS capability.  Each prior version is stored compressed as a difference to the newer version.  This allows backups with minimal storage, restores from newest version are fastest and I can delete very old backups without messing up newer version.

Comment: Would be really nice of you to tell where to get those scripts or even better if you could post them. ;)

Comment: I am now currently using http://vscsc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

If you get [Robocpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) and the [Robocopy GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) you can fiddle with it to do what you want. I use this everyday for my backups.

Comment: I created a bat file with a few robocopy lines in it which backs up my stuff to external hard drives. Then added the bat file as a task which is run once a day. Works great =)

Comment: Yep, that's how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Crashplan from here http://www4.crashplan.com/landing/index.html gives some nice options.  I'm not sure if it will back up to another internal drive but I can't see why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Some backup devices (such as the Seagate Freeagent external drive) come with supplied backup software. However, I find to cover from building fire, it can be better to use a remote backup system such [Squirrelsave](http://www.squirrelsave.co.uk), [Mozy](http://mozy.com/), [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com/) or [Jungledisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/). If you have a home network and want a machine to work as a backup machine, then [R1Soft's CDP](http://www.r1soft.com/) backup system supports Windows and Linux machines.

However, all these options are commercial - but how valuable is your data?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own, as a Python script.  It uses md5sum to detect changed files, and copies them to a standard backup subdirectory within each working directory.  Each backed up file has the same file name, with a suffix, such as `<filename>_1, <filename>_2`, etc...

This was easier when I used VMS, which made backup versions of changed files automatically.