# Is there a way to use the built-in Windows file compression tool on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression

Instead of using Right-Click/Send To/Compress (Zipped) Folder.

I am using Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I would recommend using 7-zip [as tj111 recommended](https://superuser.com/questions/30060/compressing-files-in-windows/30064#30064), to use the built in folder compression use the compact.exe command.  This is installed in the \windows\system32 folder on Windows XP.  See `compact.exe /?` for command line reference.

Comment: **This is not the same as the "Send to Compressed (zipped) Folder" GUI option**. Please see [1](http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line#comment131386_39080) and [2](http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line#comment268588_39080) for more.

Comment: This is the tool to mark files and directories so that NTFS will compress the data. It is totally unrelated to creating compressed "folders" (actually ZIP files) with the `send to` command.

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for command-line archiving in windows.  It is incredibly simple yet extremely feature rich, I have many a script that rely on it. Check out some [CLI examples](http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

Comment: I second that http://superuser.com/questions/5886/compressing-with-rar-vs-zip/5918#5918

Comment: Also, as `tj111` says: http://superuser.com/questions/29959/incremental-backup-and-sync-software/29964#29964

Comment: 7zip is also significantly faster than the built in compressor.

Comment: I would not highly recommend pushing this proprietary tool when compression has been available on platforms since the dawn of civilization.  I wish I had a nickel for every time somebody sent me one of these wholly unnecessary file formats.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this on ServerFault.com:

https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

> It's not built in to windows, but it's in the resource kit
>
> C:>compress /?
>
> Syntax:
>
> COMPRESS [-R] [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] Source Destination COMPRESS -R [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] >Source [Destination]
>
> Description: Compresses one or more files.
>
> Parameter List: -R Rename compressed files.
>
> -D Update compressed files only if out of date.
>
> -S Suppress copyright information.
>
> -ZX LZX compression. This is default compression.
>
> -Z MS-ZIP compression.
>
> Source Source file specification. Wildcards may be used.
>
> Destination Destination file | path specification. Destination may be a directory. If >Source is multiple files and -r is not specified, Destination must be a directory.
>
> Examples: COMPRESS temp.txt compressed.txt COMPRESS -R . COMPRESS -R *.exe *.dll >compressed_dir

Comment: This does not create zip-compatible files. MS-ZIP is not the same thing. It compresses one file at a time, like `gzip` on Linux, instead of creating a single `.zip` file of the whole folder.

Comment: Exactly. As mentioned as comments [1](http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line#comment131386_39080) and [2](http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line#comment268588_39080) to the answer the above seems to be quoted from.

Answer (score 2):

[using zip and unzip on the windows command line](http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip)

however, this is not about the 'built-in windows file compression tool', you'll have to download 2 executables (zip and unzip, free)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) (open source zip/unzip command line utility) and in order to increase the speed of my windows searches, gzip the resulting zip files.