# Compressing a file from command line

Tags: command-line, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compressing files in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/30060/compressing-files-in-windows)

I want to compress a file using the command line. This command-line

```
C: compact /c aa.xml
```

returns a successful message but I can't see any ZIP file in the C folder. Where is the problem?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `compact` doesn't compress things. It tells NTFS to do so.

Comment: If you want  to compress from shell, install command-line archiver and put it in path.

Answer (score 0):

The `COMPACT` command isn't for compressing file like zip compression.

If you want create zip file via the command line, try the [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) application.
Here are examples for using it from the command-line: http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples