# Best way to organize a shared photo library?

Tags: windows, linux, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need a central photo management solution for my home network](https://superuser.com/questions/251857/i-need-a-central-photo-management-solution-for-my-home-network)

My wife has a laptop with reasonably little hard drive space. I have a laptop with plenty. We have a desktop machine on Wifi that has plenty as well. We have a couple of different cameras which may be connected to my and/or my wife's laptops in no particular order. My laptop runs Ubuntu, my wife's runs Windows 7, and the desktop machine is Windows 7 as well.

I'd like some way to give everyone access to the photo library, including the ability to add photos (with duplicate import detection), tag photos, rename photos, etc. I'd rather run locally than rely on a web service if at all possible.

Any ideas? I'd lean towards some kind of shared drive on my desktop machine, which gets backed up regularly off-site. I could get Windows and Linux compatibility with Samba/windows file sharing. I'm just not sure if there's some program we can put on everyone's computer that will handle tagging and reorganization well with multiple users.

Comment: Sounds like you just need one of those picture management sites, such as Picasa. Did you try those?

Comment: For future reference, the title to the question is subjective and therefore impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation, try using [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/).
Best way to share files and stay synchronized.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. DropBox is pretty amazing on this front, and really meets all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net) free web gallery. At BitNami you can find mac, linux and windows [installers](http://bitnami.org/stack/coppermine) for it. (so, adressing well those compatibility issues) I think it would support all which you mention.