# Automatic incremental backups to a network drive (Windows)

Tags: backup, windows-backup, incremental-backup, windows-7-backup

So after learning that Windows 7 Home Premium doesn't support this, I'm looking for another solution. I would like to backup my Windows machine to my Ubuntu server. Are there any good automatic incremental backup solutions that allow backing up to a network drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/29959/incremental-backup-and-sync-software

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get Windows 7 Home Premium to do backups over the network by mounting a VHD from a network drive and setting Windows Backup to write files there.

1. Open Start Menu
2. Type "disk part"
3. Open "Create and format disk partitions"
4. In the menu choose Action -> Create VHD
5. Choose a network location and wait a long time until it's created
6. Right click on the new disk on the bottom of the window
7. Choose Initialize Disk and wait again
8. Right click again on the right side
9. Choose New Simple Volume...
10. In the wizard, assign a drive letter
11. Open Windows Backup and configure it to write backups to new drive

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Cobian Backup 11 for this. It's really straightforward to use.

1. create a new task
2. Choose incremental backup type from the general tab
3. Choose the folders to backup from the files tab, along with the network drive as the target destination
4. Choose you desired schedule from the schedule tab

Here's their web page: http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm